# how can i display a message after playing a song in the android media player?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

**hi every one**

ok so i want to display a message after playing a song in the android media player

because i want that every time that the user will play some song in the media player

it will pop up some Message to the screen .

for example:

```
the user want to play a song in the media player , so A message like "You just played a song !" will pop up to the screen
```

it is possible?

sorry for bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you mean you want to "override" it, you just want to use it inside your own activity and let your app behave accordingly.

Take a look here for how this works:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html

Comment: i edited my message , now its should be more accurate to what i wanted to ask EDIT: and i want to show the message in the media player of android after play some song